# how to add filters to elastic query when using function_score?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack

Here is my current elastic query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "ocean",
                            "fields": [],
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }}],
                    "must_not": [{
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "parentId"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "functions" : [
                {
                    "gauss": {
                            "createTime": {
                                    "origin": "2020-07-09T23:50:00",
                                    "scale": "365d",
                                    "decay": 0.3
                            }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How do I properly add **filters** to this?  I think maybe the fact that I'm using `function_score` makes this different?   I would like to add a hard filter, for example,  only show me results with `uploadUser: 'Mr. Bean'` ... but still keep the scoring in place for the results that pass this filter.

I tried using `filter` in various places, also using `must` but I either get no results or all the results.

I'm using Elastic Search 7.  Thanks for your help

Comment: can u share your sample data and result which u expect to get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below search query:

**Refer this ES official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to know more about Function score query**

```
    {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "uploadUser": "Mr. Bean"
            }
          },
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "ocean",
                "fields": [
                  
                ],
                "fuzziness": "AUTO"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "parentId"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "createTime": {
              "origin": "2020-07-09T23:50:00",
              "scale": "365d",
              "decay": 0.3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @tyler-g can you try the above search query, and let me know if this works ? And, it would be great if you can provide some sample index data also and your expected result

Comment: I tried that way and get no results unfortunately.  Without the "filter" I get several results, and I can see some of them have `uploadUser: Mr. Bean`  however as soon as I put the filter on I get no results

Comment: @tyler-g can u please share your index data and mapping, and even what search result you expect to get based on that index data ?

Comment: @tyler-g did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Yes got it working thanks for your feedback @Bhavya !

Comment: @tyler-g glad I could be of ur help :) Can u please accept this answer as well as this solved ur issue :)